# What is a Formulated CV?

Tags: cv

I am going to send my application to an organization and they have mentioned that the applicants should send us both tabular and formulated CVs.
Could you please walk me through this? What is a formulated CV? In what format should it be written? What information and in what order the information should be written?
*I completely know the tabular format for resumes but I am new to this formulated CV.*

Comment: See http://studyabroadscholarshipsuniversity.blogspot.com/2013/11/written-application-formulated-cv.html

Answer (score 2):

As best as I can gather, a “formulated CV” contains the same basic information as a tabulated CV, but in narrative form. This allows you to explain anything that might look unusual in the standard tabulated form, and also gives the foundation an additional “standard” writing sample that can be more easily compared between candidates.

Comment: Thanks. Have you got any sample for such CVs?

Comment: No. I’ve never needed to write or collect them.

Comment: Thinking about your answer, I was wondering how I can explain and write about the "Publication" and "Workshop & conferences" parts in a formulated form! what would you do if you were me :)

Comment: When I write letters of recommendation, I lump the discussion of papers with the work that they did on the given project.